# How do I start a thrift server in Scala?

Tags: scala, thrift, finagle, scrooge

I have a thrift service implemented in scala that I would like to serve. I'm using scrooge with finagle for the server. It seems to be running fine, however, whenever I try to connect a client and actually do an RPC, the client and the server seems to not do anything. My client is written in python, and I'm using thriftpy. This is how I currently start my server in scala:

```
val service = Thrift.serveIface("localhost:3000", new imple)
Await.ready(service)
```

**EDIT**

After some playing around, I got the finagle client to do an RPC. However, I am unable to connect my Finagle client to a python server. This is the error that my python server throws:

```
cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header
```

Comment: Have you tried using a Finagle client (just for the sake of debugging)?

Comment: I made a simple Finagle client to test, it doesn't connect to the scala server either. I rewrote the server implementation in Python. When I use a python client, it works, but when I use the Finagle client, nothing happens.

Comment: After some playing around, I got the finagle client to do an RPC. However, I am unable to connect my finagle client to a python server. This is the error that my python server throws:
    cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header